# Cannot access memory error in strstr implementation

Tags: c, pointers, strstr

I have the following code to implement my own version of string search in C. The string search function returns a pointer to the first occurrence in haystack of any of the entire sequence of characters specified in needle, or a null pointer if the sequence is not present in haystack. This is my code:

```
char *
mystrstr(const char *haystack, const char *needle)
{
    size_t length = 0;
    size_t i = 0;
    size_t j = 0;
    const char *p1;
    const char *p2;

    p1 = haystack;
    p2 = needle;
    assert(haystack != NULL && needle != NULL);
    while (needle[length] != '\0') {
        length++;
    }

    while (*p1 != '\0') {
        p2 = needle;
        j = 0;
        while (j < length && *p1 == *p2) {
            p1++;
            p2++;
            j++;
        }
        if (j == length) {
            return i;
        }
        p1 = p1 - j + 1;
        i++;
    }

    return NULL;
}
```

However, when I test this code, I get an error message saying that it cannot access the memory. Any ideas on what might be the issue here? Also any suggestions on how to improve the code to make it mimic the function as described above?

Comment: You never initialized `p1`. Is that supposed to be `pc1`? You also never declared `pc1`.

Comment: The code you show won't even build, much less run and crash. Please create a [mre] (including a simple `main` function that calls your function) and show it to us.

Comment: As a hint: Doesn't the compiler give you a warning about returning a `size_t` value when you're supposed to return a `char *`? Then you need to enable more warnings. Always build with extra warnings enabled, and treat them as errors that must be fixed.

Comment: This won't compile. You should change all `p1` into `pc1`. Also, `return i;` is returning an `size_t` when the return wants a pointer. You probably want: `return &haystack[i];` So, this can't be your real code if the real code compiles and runs. And, "cannot access the memory" isn't a precise error message. The program might segfault or other. What is the _exact_ behavior?

Answer (score 0):

change

```
return i;
```

to

```
return (haystack + i );
```

Comment: Or (which might be clearer to some) `return &haystack[i];`